# IE 11 vs Chrome 34 border-spacing in Twitter Bootstrap .row css class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

IE 11 applies border-spacing differently to the clearfix being used by bootstrap (looks like the Nicolas Gallagher Micro Clearfix http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).  It appears that if there is a single space as content in the clearfix, IE is not applying the border-spacing (If content is set to some sort of text the border-spacing works).

```
<div style="border-spacing:0 20px">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm looking for a nice way to bring IE behavior in line with Chrome.

Also, I'm not a CSS guy, so any explanation of the difference or correction of my understanding of what's happening would be a plus.  Is IE or Chrome correct in the way they handle border-spacing for this particular case?

Here's a fiddle showing the problem, http://jsfiddle.net/F2EXZ/1/
IE11 has little to no spacing between the rows, Chrome 34 has obviously more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up going with a localized fix for now.  Just a small part of a single page on my site is needs border spacing to work properly with bootstrap.  Hoping something better turns up here, I'll leave the question unanswered for now.

```
.test .row::before, .test .row::after {
    display:table-row;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F2EXZ/3/